# Can I export a puppet warp mesh of photoshop to a file?

Tags: photoshop

I wish to export to a file the mesh/vertices/triangles of puppet warp in photoshop, and the warped vertices (the diff of each vertices maybe?).
Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, **no**. There is no standard photoshop function to save a puppet warp mesh. You *can* however save a *liquify* mesh. Liquify has similarities to puppet warp, in that they both warp the image with a mesh, but the way it is controlled is quite different.

Also, if you choose this method, be mindful that the mesh is relative to the size of the canvas. You'll want subsequent images to be the exact same pixel dimensions as the one you saved the mesh from. Also, if there are cropped areas of your image that have not been deleted, they will be factored into the point of reference. So if you crop, it's easiest to crop to the visible image area (crop/delete cropped pixels) before performing the liquify.